# Ruby on Rails - Ajax Pagination EXTRA_CONTENT_DISCARDED

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, pagination

Well guys, I'm trying to paginate with ajax.

I have this partial called `_ofertas_ativas.html.erb

```
<h1>Ofertas Activas</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
  <%= ajax_section :id => "page", :render => "page" %>
  </tr>
</table>
<p><%= link_to "ver todas", ofertas_path %></p>`
```

The page partial here:

```
<%= ajax_loadzone do %>
  <% @ofertas_ativas.each do |oferta| %>
    <td>
      <p><%= link_to oferta.titulo, oferta_path(oferta) %></p>
      <p><%= oferta.data_inicio %> a <%= oferta.data_fim %></p>
      <p><%= oferta.corpo %></p>
      <% if @user.role == "candidato" %>
        <%= link_to "Candidatar-me", "/candidatura/#{current_user.candidato.id}/#{oferta.id}" , class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
      <% elsif current_user?(@user) %>
        <%= link_to "Editar", edit_oferta_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= ajax_links :section_id => "page" do %>
  <%= will_paginate @ofertas_ativas %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.role == "entidade"
      @user_ent = Entidade.find_by("user_id = ?",params[:id])
      @ofertas_ativas = @user_ent.ofertas.where("ativa = ?",true).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 2)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        ajax_respond format, :section_id => "page"
      end
```

When i click the next button or the number this message appears:

```
    AJAX Pagination EXTRA_CONTENT_DISCARDED:
Extra content returned by AJAX request ignored. Only a portion of the page content returned by the server was required. To fix this, explicitly call ajax_respond :section_id => "page" to render only the partial view required. This warning can be turned off in the ajax_pagination initializer file.
```

Is it because I have the _ofertas_ativas partial? I really don't know how to fix this. I still don't understand very well this respond_to in the controller.

Does someone know what's up?

Comment: Are you using rails 4

Comment: Yes i am using rails 4. But i don't think that's the problem. is it? :/

Comment: this gem having issue with rails 4 I am putting this in answer block

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs when you have any issue in content returned from rails controller see here https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/ajax_pagination.js.erb. You can also mute this warning in initializer `config/initializers/ajax_pagination.rb` like :

```
AjaxPagination.config do |config| config.warnings = false end
```

But this is also produces issue with rails 4 see here https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination/issues/8

There are few more issues related to rails 4 with this gem https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination/issues

Comment: I seriously think it's just the way I'm doing it. Cause ALL! examples I saw and see is just for the index. No one shows you how to do it out of index. I am doing it on a show page. where I want to paginate a list of items.

Comment: Try it on your index as well. But it's issue related to rails version. So I think you should move to some other gem.

Comment: In the index it works but it throws the warning the same. But the ajax pagination works. it goes to the other page after the warning without reloading the page

Comment: You can't avoid this warning in rails 4. So move to other gem is good idea from myside

Comment: not yet. I even tried a railscasts in here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

and still doesn't work. I'm kinda stuck

Comment: I tried almost eveything I saw in terms of solutions. Nothing works. I just don't know right now

Comment: Try use kaminari with ujs link here http://www.joshondevelopment.com/post/3752155526/ajax-pagination-with-kaminari

Answer (score 0):

if this is of any help:
I commented the warning code within the gem itself. 
gems/ajax_pagination-0.6.3/lib/assets/javascripts/ajax_pagination.js.erb

line 197

```
// <% if AjaxPagination.warnings %>

// alert("AJAX Pagination EXTRA_CONTENT_DISCARDED:\nExtra content returned by AJAX request ignored. Only a portion of the page content returned by the server was required. To fix this, explicitly call ajax_respond :section_id => \"" + section_id + "\" to render only the partial view required. This warning can be turned off in the ajax_pagination initializer file.");

// <% end %>
```

The alert is all one line**

So far no other issues, will update if there are. You're more or less telling rails to do the same thing through the config file.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to Ruby/Rails but this is my take on the problem.

I am not sure why the problem appears, but let's say that it's a compatibility issue with Rails 4.*

Don't comment out the alert code or disable warnings. This warning is legitimate. It says that your server returns full page instead of just the needed fragment. It takes more bandwidth and puts more load on the server because it renders the whole page.

So this is how I solved the problem:

In **config/initializers/mime_types.rb** register your new custom mime type

```
Mime::Type.register "text/html", :ajax
```

You can name it however you want. I chose "ajax".

Notice that it is the "text/html" type that Rails already has defined by default.

Then rename view file **_ofertas_ativas.html.erb to _ofertas_ativas.ajax.erb**.

Then in your controller replace the line:

```
ajax_respond format, :section_id => "ofertas_ativas"
```

with

```
format.ajax { render :partial => "ofertas_ativas" }
```

Now your respond_to block look like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.ajax { render :partial => "ofertas_ativas" }
end
```

The ajax request that "ajax_pagination" gem makes has accept: text/html. And now you have two mime type handlers for text/html defined.

If this second line didn't exist, Rails would execute default ajax mime type handler, which is JS, so index.js.erb would be rendered. But becuase this is ajax request and there is non-default html mime type registered (ajax) it will try to find _ofertas_ativas.ajax.erb.

I hope this helps.

P.S. I definitely suggest using some other gem.